# File handle array

Tags: perl

I wanted to choose what data to put into which file depending on the index. However, I seem to be stuck with the following.

I have created the files using an array of file handles:

```
my @file_h;
my $file;
foreach $file (0..11)
{
    $file_h[$file]= new IT::File ">seq.$file.fastq";
}

$file= index;
print $file_h[$file] "$record_r1[0]$record_r1[1]$record_r1[2]$record_r1[3]\n";
```

However, I get an error for some reason in the last line. Help anyone....?

Comment: This is an oddity of Perl's syntax, since filehandles weren't originally even variables, much less more complicated lvalues.

Comment: What is the error?  Also, could you contrive a complete, self contained example?  (That would answer some immediate questions like, do you really mean IT::File [sic]?  Do you mean `index()` or `$index`?)

Answer (score 20):

That should simply be:

```
my @file_h;
for my $file (0..11) {
    open($file_h[$file], ">", "seq.$file.fastq")
       || die "cannot open seq.$file.fastq: $!";
}

# then later load up $some_index and then print 
print { $file_h[$some_index] } @record_r1[0..3], "\n";
```

Comment: Interestingly `flock $file_h[$some_index],LOCK_EX` works without brackets. Does anyone know why? What is exactly a filehandle in perl?

Answer (score 5):

You can always use the object-oriented syntax:

```
$file_h[$file]->print("$record_r1[0]$record_r1[1]$record_r1[2]$record_r1[3]\n");
```

Also, you can print out the array more simply:

```
$file_h[$file]->print(@record_r1[0..3],"\n");
```

Or like this, if those four elements are actually the whole thing:

```
$file_h[$file]->print("@record_r1\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the `$file_h[$file]` to a temporary variable first:

```
my @file_h;
my $file;
my $current_file;

foreach $file (0..11)
{
    $file_h[$file]= new IT::File ">seq.$file.fastq";
}

$file= index;
$current_file = $file_h[$file];

print $current_file "$record_r1[0]$record_r1[1]$record_r1[2]$record_r1[3]\n";
```

As far as I remember, Perl doesn't recognize it as an output handle otherwise, complaining about invalid syntax.